# Can I modify the pixel value of frames(to hide some information) on extracting it from a video file and then generating the new video?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, information-hiding

Can I modify the pixel value of frames(to hide some information) after extracting it from a video file and then generating the new video with the help of modified (in terms of pixel value) frames so that I can retrieve my information on again extracting the frames from new video?

I've used OpenCV to try this but it seems there's some compression being done on frames while extracting them or maybe while putting them together because I was not able to retrieve my hidden information in the pixels. 
Do you know is this achievable? And if yes, then please suggest me a way to do this in python.

[I have tried this code](https://medium.com/@iKhushPatel/convert-video-to-images-images-to-video-using-opencv-python-db27a128a481) but it results in loss of my information on pixel level because I think some compression is being done somewhere.

Comment: Could you please share your code, result, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to perform encryption on the faces detected in the video so that I can obtain a video that has random ordering of pixels inside the box around the faces so that you can't see the faces. And I should be able to decrypt the faces to get the original video.